# Why if logic can't contain undefined

Tags: javascript, logic

I have the following code

```
if (users[username]["password"] == password) {
  console.log("user auth!");
}
```

So if the password match it login but somehow if the username doesn't exist it'll result `users[username]["password"]` to undefined, and break the code, so I was wondering how do I let the if pass `false` statement when it meets undefined instead of stop the code?

Comment: `if(users[username] && users[username].password === password)`

Comment: is it `users[username]` or `users['username']`?

Comment: Like `if (username in users && users[username].password === password)`?

Comment: @MuthuKumaran I'm guessing the former because `username` is most likely a string or expression holding the username.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran it's user[username] since I'm using `passportjs`'s `passport-local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo = {}
foo.bar // You will get an undefined.
foo.bar.baz // You will get a TypeError if there's no bar in foo.
```

It is because the JavaScript engine is not able to read property of undefined.

And replacing the condition with `foo.bar && foo.bar.baz` may solve your problem.

In this way, if `foo.bar` is undefined, the value of this logical expression will be set to `undefined` when the engine meets the `foo.bar` and gets an `undefined`. The engine won't go on and try to get the value of `foo.bar.baz`.

But if `foo.bar` is defined, the engine will go an and the value of the expression will be set to `foo.bar.baz` correctly.

It i the features of logical operators in JavaScript.
You can find more details here
[Logical Operators - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: I think so. It is shorter than the typeof way and in way and applied widely.